# flask static image filenames with non-alphabet characters not working

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

Have not found anyone complaining about this yet, but:
Have a flask app, normal static folder with js, css, and and image folder under it.
The css, js go to the web page normally from the static folder, but the images:

sky1.jpg    works.

sky_1.jpg  does not work. Get a 404 in chrome.

works:

img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imagesUI/sky1.jpg') }}"

does not work:

img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imagesUI/sky_1.jpg') }}"

Is there a file naming convention in flask that precludes any other character than alphabetic and numeric?

I want to put date info in the filename and it is not allowing it.

ubuntu 18.04

debugging under VSC

flask dev server

Debug on

Thx

Comment: I'm new to flask and using windows, I have try Koala1.jpg,  Koala_1.jpg and Koal_a.jpg and Koala_2020-10-28.jpg, all images show up, just remember to rename the image after changing the src. You say flask is not allowing date info in filename, so does it raise error? Sorry that I may not able to help but just interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `src="{{ url_for('static', filename='imagesUI/sky_1.jpg') }}`

use `src='/static/imagesUI/sky_1.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

use `src='/static/imagesUI/sky_1.jpg'` in img tag that might do it